# RestKit single success block

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm calling object requests (i.e. "postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:") on many places around my app, using the singleton RKObjectManager.

Can I make a single block which will get called as the success block for each of the calls? (avoiding the code duplication)

I tried to subclass RKObjectManager but couldn't find the right method to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the block as an instance variable that can be referenced from where you are making your RKObjectManager calls.

```
void (^callback)(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, RKMappingResult * mappingResult);
```

This defines a block named "callback" that returns void and takes two parameters. Initialize this with the following code:

```
callback = ^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operation, RKMappingResult * mappingResult) {
  // Your completion code here
};
```

Now you can reuse this block code in your post requests by using the variable name "callback" as the success block parameter.

Comment: That might be an option. But one still need to explicitly call the callback in each request. Isn't there a more elegant way? Seems odd that there's no method to override to achieve this.

Comment: I haven't found anything that lets you set a default success block. Another option would be to write a function postObject:path:parameters in your own singleton that has the predefined blocks. However, this is similar to the instance variable option.

Comment: yeah and that's also means I'll have to write all the related methods as well. (getObject:.., deleteObject:..., etc.)